# Find Specific String in Richtextbox C#

Tags: c#

Hello I need to find a word in my Richtextbox I need to find the string "ERP Points and ERP Bonus Point"

Here's the contents of a Richboxtext:
https://pastebin.com/vdPQx5E4

Now here's my code:

```
string resultString = "";
foreach (string line in richTextBox2.Lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("ERP Points") || line.Contains("ERP Bonus Point"))
    {
        resultString = richTextBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox2.Find("ERP", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase)).ToString();
        var result = Regex.Replace(line, @"\D", "");
        string output = Regex.Replace(line, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show(resultString);
        MessageBox.Show(output);
        FontArial = 1;
        FontSize = Int32.Parse(output);
    }
    else
    {
        FontArial = 0;
        FontSize = 0;
    }


}
```

and here's my another version which gives me 153 and I don't know where the program gets that:

```
resultString = richTextBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox2.Find("ERP", RichTextBoxFinds.None)).ToString();
var result = Regex.Replace(line, @"\D", "");
string output = Regex.Replace(resultString, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
MessageBox.Show(resultString.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(output);
if (output != "")
{
    FontArial = 1;
    FontSize = Int32.Parse(output);
}
else
{
    FontArial = 0;
    FontSize = 0;
}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I need to get the ERP Points: line and ERP Bonus Points: line but I was not able to get it, it gives me wrong value, What's wrong with my code.

Comment: what happens when you debug it as it goes through it

Comment: You want to find line number?

Comment: No, I need to find the exact string: 
"ERP Points:
ERP Bonus Point: 1500"

Comment: Then why you search for "ERP Points" and "ERP Bonus Point"? Just search for your exact string "ERP Points: ERP Bonus Point: 1500". And I don't understand why are you assigning `output` string to `FontSize`

Comment: those font size and font arial are just naming convention that is wrong, ignore that. I can't pin point exactly the ERP Points" and "ERP Bonus Point because its dynamic, I'm scraping a list of job post and each post have different ERP Bonus Points like they got 1500 or 2000 or 500, its not static